# Can you split washer/dryer and share with standard 3 prong

Tags: electrical, dryer, washing-machine

I’m not great with all of the proper terminology here. We have what appears to be a 30amp plug for out washer/dryer combo. I want to mount and hang out dyson vacuum charging station in the same space as the washer/dryer to have it out of the way.

Is it safe to get a splitter, plugging one portion into the washer/dryer and a converter into the other, with the dyson plugged into that

Will I provide too much power to the dyson and too little to the washer/dryer?

Comment: It's hard to give answers on "what appears to be".  We'll need some pictures of your existing wiring and breaker setup.

Comment: What make and model is your washer/dryer combo, and do you not have a 120V circuit to your laundry space?!

Comment: it sounds like something that isn't as straightforward as I would've liked so I think i'm just gonna have an electrician come out sometime soon and straighten it all out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say NO based on the info provided. a 30 amp circuit will first normally be 240v.  But even if it is something I have not seen the Dyson will only be rated for a 20 amp circuit so making a splitter would create multiple code violations if regulated by the NEC.

If it is a 20 amp 120v people all splitters all the time I do not allow them at my work if they need additional outlets I put in new circuits. However there are UL listed splitters so in that if used they would be “safe”.
the code for the laundry circuit is that it has no other outlets so it would be a minor issue and you would only need to worry if the code police show up. (Code police not real a joke)

Comment: thanks for the info! I'm too afraid to get it wrong and/or make a poor choice, so i'll just have someone come out. Was afraid it wouldn't be super straightforward

Answer (score 1):

No, because the code doesn't allow 15 and 20A receptales on 30A circuits. At least one reason for this is the current that it takes to trip a 30A breaker is so high that the small cords for small devices can overheat, melt, and start a fire before the larger breaker trips.

At least one [published time curve](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aX9MD-ZA7HJIrcMix6SyC3AJpQ5Zx1j47PyYHBgqHaW5AR-evHCqrgGlDvXZKUQW2azy5LxXE5i7JecP-w6hvcZ0ay80WMy-BrE_Nr41YHpkWDMseciKcpmXbAaCnsiGAACHLhs) shows some breakers can hold up to 2.5x the rated current for one minute before tripping and be within specs. 75A on a little charger cord is kind of scary.